# Change minSdkVersion and maxSdkVersion

Tags: android, version, store, google-apps-marketplace

I have 2 same app (different versions) in Google Play Store but i want to Change their minSdkVersion and maxSdkVersion without Reuploading to Google Play Store, How can i do this ?

Comment: You need to update. That's the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to handle with app push. Sadly, Play store console doesn't have this feature

From play store console, you can just exclude devices based on vendor or ROM or System level properties.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, minSdkVersion and maxSdkVersion stay inside your app.gradle file, you have to update them and regenerate your apk. Don't forget to update your versionCode otherwise apk will be rejected.